# Leaflet popup won't open (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working on a map view for a react application which I'm using Leaflet for ([react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet)). I'm able to plot markers on the map, but the popups that I have bound to them won't open when clicked.  I first tried using `<Marker>` and `<Popup>` components, but [this](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/11) Github issue suggested it might be better to just grab the leaflet map object from the map component and explicitly bind markers to it.  This is what I have:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.map = this.refs.map.leafletElement;
    this.state.rows.map((row) => {
        var marker = L.marker([row.coordinate.latitude, row.coordinate.longitude]);
        marker.addTo(this.map);

        var popupText = util.format('<b>%s</b>', row.venue)
        for(var i = 0; i < row.beers.length; i++){
            var beer = row.beers[i];
            popupText += util.format('<br>%s: %s - %d', beer.brewery, beer.name, beer.rating)
        }

        marker.bindPopup(popupText);
        //marker.on('click', function(e){console.log('clicked!')})
    });
}

render(){
    const cover = {position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, top: 50, bottom: 0};
    return(
        <div>
            <Map scrollWheelZoom={false} center={this.state.position} zoom={14} style={cover} ref="map">
                <TileLayer
                  url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                  attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                />
            </Map>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Even if I uncomment the `marker.on('click'...)` line, the `console.log` never seems to fire.  Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/11) is out of date as of [October 7, 2015](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/7b75fcb263e3b4bf10ccbc0076e5a5902ba104da/CHANGELOG.md#v080-2015-10-07). Adding children with action listeners has been fixed. Here is an example of how you can add zoom actions in a popup.

```
<Marker position={position}>
    <Popup>
      <span>
        <button onClick={this.zoomOut}>
          Zoom out
        </button >
        <button onClick = {this.zoomIn}>
          Zoom in
        </button>
      </span>
    </Popup >
  </Marker>
```

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hu0Lewuz/1/) is a working example.